# Adjusting vertical alignment of multi-line equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, multline

Trying to get an output which looks like this:

[image]

What I've achieved so far, using the `multline` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
    a + b + c + d \\+ e + f + g = 0
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any suggestions? (Asking for a friend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I much prefer the version in the question but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
    a + b + c + d \\+ e + f + g
\end{multlined}
 = 0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this layout is more acceptable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}%% loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
    a + b & + c & & + d \\[-1ex]\:{}+ e & + f & & + g
\end{alignedat}
=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]